# Automatically install package's all dependencies with Poetry

Tags: python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I'd like to create a package which

- Is build and maintained with poetry
- Is installed with Poetry
- Contains a long list of extra dependencies which will evolve over time
- Have a Poetry automatically install extra dependencies unless a specific list is given in `pyproject.toml`

Is this possible with Poetry, i.e. is there `all` dependency declaration either at the package's `pyproject.toml` description or the project's `pyproject.toml` description?

Comment: not sure I understand the question here?  `poetry install` does install all dependencies mentioned in the pyproject.toml.